# Are Unamed Variables in Function Call Static

Tags: php, variables

So we call some function in PHP:

```
do_something('foodabaa');
function do_something($subject)
{
  static $pattern = '~foo~';
  return preg_replace($pattern, 'bar', $subject);
}
```

Is the replacement value `bar` static, or is it dynamic so each call to the function reinitializes it?

By all means add info about other programming languages besides PHP.

Comment: In your example this value is static anyway since you use string constant 'bar'.

Comment: Perhaps you did confuse replacement and pattern?

Comment: @hindmost...No, the question is quite clear, I put a static variable for reference. I'm only interested in if `'bar'` is static or dynamic, I assume static.

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) (Example #5):

```
function test()
{
    static $a = 0;
    echo $a."\n\r";
    $a++;
}
```

> Now, $a is initialized only in first call of function and every time
>   the test() function is called it will print the value of $a and
>   increment it.

So if you will call it twice:

```
test();
test();
```

Return will be:

```
0
1
```

Lets back to your example. There is same situation, `$pattern` will be initialized just once.

**Inside C/C++**

```
void foo()
{
    static int a = 0;
    printf("%d", a);
    x++;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

```
0
1
```

That's the common behavior in many languages which are using static variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm not asking about static variables declared with `static` keyword, but unamed/anonymous variables.

Comment: What you mean as unnamed/anonymous variable?

Comment: @Kasyx...As is `trim('string  ')`: is `'string  '` static or reinitialized on each call, however I'm talking about within a function, as in the question. I assume it's static as PHP/developers would know that it could never change, but just wanted verification. Would hate to develop an incorrect mindset, if you know what I mean